# What equalizer replaces pulse effects in Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: sound, equalizer

I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04, but pulse effects was disabled. What replaces it?

Answer (score 3):

Easy Effects is the new version of Pulse effects and has almost the same user interface.

```
sudo apt-get install easyeffects
```

Comment: That did the trick for me whitout problems, thanks.